# Does XElement.Remove() function thread safe?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, thread-safety, xelement

Does XElement.**Remove()** function thread safe?such as in **Parallel.Foreach**.and I can ensure the nodes in different threads are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of LINQ to XML is thread-safe for modifications.

In general, you will almost never find a mutable thread-safe object, unless it has been specifically designed for thread-safety (`System.Collections.Concurrent`).

The one major exception to this rule (Java's original collection framework) is widely regarded as a mistake, and has been replaced with separate concurrent and non-thread-safe versions.

Comment: so I should store the node in **System.Collections.Concurrent** such as ConcurrentBag<XElement> and remove then all after the thread operation?

Comment: @TommyLike: It entirely depends on what you're doing.  Thread-safety is not simple; you need to figure out what might run in parallel and how they might interfere.  See also my blog post, http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/